# Unable to show list and upload file from dropbox in swift 5

Tags: dropbox, swift5, xcode12

I am not able to see the list of my dropbox files and cannot able to upload files from dropbox to my app.

I've seen this response from the console.
"Bad Input: Error in call to API function "files/list_folder": Your app is not permitted to access this endpoint because it does not have the required scope 'files.metadata.read'. The owner of the app can enable the scope for the app using the Permissions tab on the App Console."

I have two applications with the same code.
The first app, it's showing a list and I can upload files from my dropbox account.
But in the second app, I am not able to watch the list and am not able to upload files from the dropbox account.
I also checked that I am given propper permissions from dropbox developers console for both my app but in first app it is working and in second app it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Discuss-Dropbox-Developer-API/Unable-to-upload-file-from-my-ios-app/m-p/533160 ]

This "Your app is not permitted to access this endpoint" error indicates that the app for the access token you're using to make the call does not have the necessary scope needed for calling that particular endpoint. As indicated by the error message in this case, the app would need the "files.metadata.read" scope.

You can add it via the "Permissions" tab on the app's info page on [the App Console](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps). Then you can get a new access token with that scope added and use that new access token to make this API call.